# Pig Script not Flattening Tuples Correctly

Tags: java, json, parsing, apache-pig

Pig novice here. I have data that is is a JSON string of varying length, with key value pairs of city names contained in quotes and values an integer:

```
{"Chicago, Illinois": 123, "London, England, Great Britain": 555, "Mexico City, Federal District, Mexico": 333 ...}
{"Chicago, Illinois": 555, "London, England, Great Britain": 222, "Dublin, Ireland": 888 ...}
```

Desired output:

```
Chicago, Illinois
Mexico City, Federal District, Mexico
London, England, Great Britain
Dublin, Ireland
```

I am trying to create a list of unique city names from all the JSON strings in my collection (one JSON string per line).

```
cities_data = LOAD 'hbase://facebook_insights'
                    USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('c:cities_frequency', '-caster=HBaseBinaryConverter -loadKey true -gte 20141201')
          AS (key:chararray, cities_frequency);

tokenized_cities = FOREACH cities_data GENERATE flatten(TOKENIZE(cities_frequency,'"')) as caught_cities;

filtered_cities_data = FILTER tokenized_cities by NOT STARTSWITH(caught_cities, ':');

city_group = GROUP filtered_cities_data BY caught_cities;
unique_cities = FOREACH city_group GENERATE group;

STORE unique_cities INTO 'output/cities';
```

Most of the city names are in tact in the output however several of the city names are broken up. For example:

```
Chic
ago, Illinois
Mexico City, Federal District, 
Mexico
London, England, Great Britain
Dublin, Ireland
```

When I tokenize each cities_frequency, it creates a bag of tuples (which I confirmed are indeed correct with the tuples containing the entire city names form the key).

Here is a sample output when cities_frequency is tokenized using a double quote:

```
{({),(Tulsa, OK),(: 1, ),(Ponte Vedra Beach, FL),(: 2, ),(Virginia Beach, VA),(: 1, ),(Hollywood, FL),(: 1, ),(Riyadh, Ar Riyad, Saudi Arabia),(: 2, ),(Lake Panasoffkee, FL),(: 1,     ),(Bowmantown, TN),(: 1, ),(Duluth, GA),(: 1, ),(Atlanta, GA),(: 2, ),(Jacksonville Beach, FL),(: 2, ),(Cushing, OK),(: 3, ),(Miri, Sarawak, Malaysia),(: 2, ),(Davenport, IA),(: 1, ),(Saint Petersburg, FL),(: 1, ),(Ocala, FL),(: 1, ),(Osasco, S\u00e3o Paulo, Brazil),(: 1, ),(Haywards Heath, England, United Kingdom),(: 1, ),(Chicago, IL),(: 1, ),(Skipperville, AL),(: 1, ),(Grain Valley, MO),(: 1, ),(Jacksonville, FL),(: 14, ),(Atlantic Beach, FL),(: 1, ),(Carlton, OR),(: 1, ),(Gainesville, FL),(: 3, ),(Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia),(: 1})}
{({),(Baker, FL),(: 3, ),(Playas, Guayas, Ecuador),(: 1, ),(Port Hueneme, CA),(: 1, ),(Pace, FL),(: 2, ),(St. Louis, MO),(: 1, ),(Tampa, FL),(: 1, ),(Crestview, FL),(: 19, ),(Wells, MN),(: 1, ),(Daphne, AL),(: 1, ),(Scottsdale, AZ),(: 1, ),(Niceville, FL),(: 4, ),(Los Angeles, CA),(: 1, ),(DeFuniak Springs, FL),(: 1, ),(Moorpark, CA),(: 1, ),(Cantonment, FL),(: 1, ),(Urbana, IL),(: 1, ),(Albuquerque, NM),(: 1, ),(Fort Walton Beach, FL),(: 1, ),(Port Barre, LA),(: 1, ),(Harrisburg, AR),(: 1, ),(McCalla, AL),(: 1, ),(Ville Platte, LA),(: 1, ),(De Funiak Springs, FL),(: 1, ),(Destin, FL),(: 1, ),(Orlando, FL),(: 1, ),(Pensacola, FL),(: 1})}
```

It is when the tuples are flattened

```
FOREACH cities_data flatten(TOKENIZE(cities_frequency, '"')) as caught_cities
```

however that some of this splicing happens. Is there something I am overlooking? I've tried using:

```
FOREACH cities_data GENERATE REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(cities_frequencies, '"([a-zA-Z])*"') as caught_cities;
```

with no success (from piggybank.jar). Empty results are returned.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste the output of following command. DUMP cities_data;  and DESCRIBE cities_data; ?. please update the output of the above command in the question section.

Comment: If you are not forced to load this data from HBase, there's a JSONLoader in Pig which might make separating entries easier. If you are forced to load it from HBase I would personally write a UDF that parses a complete line as JSON (using Java or Python) and returns a pig bag that contains the entries. That way further processing should be much easier.